# How Verify if SFC has found errors

Tags: windows-7, sfc

I want to run SFC command in a cmd file. At the ende of the check i would like to verify whether SFC has found errors (that an error message can be displayed) or not. Unfortunately errorlevel seems not to be working with sfc - it always shows 0 in my experience, no matter if it found corrupted files or not.

Some ideas how to solve this?

Update: To be more precise what i want is this. The cmd starts some backupjobs etc. then starts the sfc/scannow. In case sfc found corrupted files and repaired them i want that some alert can be triggered and the cmd comes to a stopp, so that in the next morning i can see that something was fishy (I know that /scannow should already have fixed everything - but i want to have a look at this).Usually for this kind of "Errorhandling" i read out the %errorlevel% to find out if a command produced an error. But this is not possible with sfc since - in my experience - it always shows 0 for errorlevel no matter what. I'm looking now for a workaround. End of Update.

Greetings!

Comment: What do you mean verify if sfc has found errors?  It either finds errors and tells you ( depending on the type of scan you performed ) or it detects the errors and proceeds to fix them.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, i tried to clarify. Added more Info in the Thread.

Comment: Run **findstr /c:"[SR]" C:\Windows\logs\CBS\CBS.log >sfcdetails.txt** open the sfcdetails.txt and look if Windows is unable to restore files or if it was able to fix all issues.

Comment: to go wHi magicandre1981, going with findstr through the cbs.log is actually what i'm doing right now ;) The problem with this is that you might be missing something since you can not know all error-phrases (rerairing corrupted, repaired file...). That's why i wanted to know if there is a more "high level" way of doing that - more a yes or no type of answer... But since %errorlevel% seems not to be working (at least in my understanding) maybe that's not possible...

Answer (score 1):

Alright... So i spent hours on searching the internet about anything i could find for SFC related stuff and this is what i can suggets now in 2023 jan 3:

First when you check for the errorlevel and when you echo it to find out i highly suggest to do that:

> and within a setlocal delayedexpension
> its not %errorlevel% but !errorlevel!

#### errorlevel handling

```
@REM SFC /scannow command
SFC /scannow & errLevel = %errorlevel%

@REM You can add some code here as well as much as you want

if %errLevel% EQU 1 @echo case of standard error of SFC operation
if %errLevel% EQU -1073741510 @echo SFC was forced to quit by the user with ctrl+d
if %errLevel% EQU 0 @echo case of success operation
```

The benefits of that is you don't have to handle errorlevel right after the sfc
command. So you can put the ifs wherever you want in your batch (.bat) file.

Hope someone read this and i hope it would be helpful.